# Automorphisms of profinite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let $d,n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $p$ a prime number. Let $F$ be a free pro-$p$ group on $d$ generators. Is there an automorphism of $F$ of order $n$?

Comment: I guess that Aut($F$) is (residually-$p$)-by-GL($d$,$p$); if so there are various restrictions on $n$ (e.g. it can't be a too big prime).

Comment: Is this the $p$-part of the profinite completion of a free (nonabelian) group on $d$ generators?

Comment: No. This is the pro-$p$ completion of a finitely generated free group.

Comment: Yves Cornulier's comment answers the question for $n$ coprime to $p$: indeed, $\mathrm{Aut}(F)$ is pro-$p$-by-$\mathrm{GL}(d,p)$, so $F$ has an automorphism of order $n$ if and only if $n$ divides $|\mathrm{GL}(d,p)|$.  The next question to ask is whether $F$ has automorphisms of order $p^k$ for arbitrarily large $k$.

Comment: Yes, and it is also not that clear to me if there are automorphisms of order $ap^k$ for some $a$ coprime to $p$.

Comment: I think you meant that $F$ has automorphisms of order $n$ iff there is an element of order $n$ in the aforementioned matrix group (divisibility of the cardinality by $n$ is not a priori sufficient).